# How to join multiple uneven views

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to join multiple views with uneven data. Let me explain with sample data

View1:

```
DATE | COL2
150 rows
```

View2:

```
DATE | COL3
30 rows
```

View3:

```
DATE | COL4
15 rows
```

so i want to get data like:

OUTPUT:

```
DATE | COL2 | COL3 | COL4
150 rows with nulls on some columns
```

DATE column is MONTH:YEAR like 02/2019. Each view made with DATEPART MONTH and YEAR columns and gathered in a single column. So i don't want to have duplicated DATE rows.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN`/`FULL OUTER JOIN`? Some sample data and expected results would make this question answerable.

Comment: you are right let me edit question. Full outer join won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use left join base on the union of the date

```
select t1.date, v1.COL2, v2.COL3, v3.COL4
from(

  select date from view1
  union
  select date from view2
  union
  select date from view2

) t1 
left join view1 v1 on t1.date = v1.date 
left join view2 v2 on t1.date = v2.date 
left join view1 v3 on t1.date = v3.date
```

Comment: what if v2 has more date rows?

Comment: wow! thank you. I don't know why and how but this works. Could you please explain me why it didn't skipped date rows even main view has the least amount of dates?

Comment: The question says v1 has 150 rows and v2 has 30 rows (in this example).but what you might mean is dates outside of the range of v1 but the union operator loses the dupes and then the left join means that all dates are represented etc...

Comment: Anyway if v2 has more rows the left join means all dates in t1 are represented in the first join (with v1) and the v2 and v3 will just work with those dates if you like.

Comment: Then from subselect just select the distinct date  present in all the 3 table  .. based on the set of distinct date each view is joined  for the macthing  .. row .. for  eval the numbers of rows returned  you just need  to see  the result fo form subselect

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use `full join`:

```
select coalesce(v3.date, v2.date, v1.date) as date, v1.col2, v2.col3, v3.col4
from view1 v1 full join
     view2 v2
     on v2.date = v1.date full join
     view3 v3
     on v3.date = coalesce(v2.date, v1.date);
```

This is preferable to a `left join` solution because each view is accessed only once, so any code in the view is not run multiple times.